# Dynamics: after importing the package open web-resource html page

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have to open web-resource ("**settings.html**") after importing package in Dynamics 365.

How can I do that in MS Dynamics 365 v 8.2?

I've heard something about "**post import action**",  but I got nothing about it.

Comment: You can't interact with clients from a server-side operation

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for adding configuration page in solution.

```
1   Create an HTML Web Resource in your solution
2   Add the created Web Resource as a Configuration Page in the Solution Information
```

[Reference](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/add-a-configuration-page-solution/)

Comment: Thank you,  but  actually i want something like this:
after importing the solution,  the window with settings.html will open automatically!
But your answer doesn't solve it :(

Comment: Unfortunately this is the maximum supported stuff we can do. All the ISV are following this product feature only :(

Comment: SO,  I cannot open custom HTML page after importing the package ?